# Leaflet map interaction in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, leaflet

I'm pretty new to AngularJS and I have a Leaflet app loaded through a directive. The leaflet configuration is shamelessly taken from http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html which loads up a map with highlighted zipcodes.

My question is I want to load up a url from a ajax call that returns a Plotly url. How do I replace the map with an iframe plotly embed within Angular.

Caution the code is very crude and mostly pure javascript with the directive:

Controller:

```
app.controller('MapController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = '';
    $scope.getData = function(URL) {
        $http.get(URL).success(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
        })
        return $scope.data;
    }
}]);
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('map', function() {
    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var geojson;
        var info;


        var zip_data = $.getJSON("data/live", function(data){on_json_received(data)})


        function on_json_received(data){
            L.mapbox.accessToken = 'token';
            var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'xxx.xx')
            .setView([37.760, -122.435], 13);
            info = L.control();


            info.onAdd = function (map) {
                this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
                this.update();
                return this._div;
            };

            // method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
            info.update = function (e) {
                if(e)
                    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>'+e.target.feature.id+', Sentiment</h4>' +  e.target.feature.sentiment
                else
                    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Zipcode, Sentiment</h4>' 
            };

            info.addTo(map);

            var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

            legend.onAdd = function (map) {

                var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                    grades = [-1,-.7, -.5, -.3, 0, .3, .5, .7,1],
                    labels = [];

                // loop through our density intervals and generate a label with a colored square for each interval
                for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                    div.innerHTML +=
                        '<i style="background:' + getColor(grades[i] + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                        grades[i] + (grades[i + 1] ? '&ndash;' + grades[i + 1] + '<br>' : '+</br>');
                }

                return div;
            };

            legend.addTo(map);



            geojson = L.geoJson(data,{style: style,onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map);


        }

        function getColor(d) {

            return  d > .7 ? '#800026' :
                    d > .5  ? '#BD0026' :
                    d > .3  ? '#E31A1C' :
                    d > 0  ? '#FC4E2A' :
                    d > -.3   ? '#FD8D3C' :
                    d > -.5   ? '#FEB24C' :
                    d > -.7   ? '#FED976' :
                               '#FFEDA0';
        }

        function style(feature) {
            return {
                fillColor: getColor(feature.sentiment),
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'white',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.7
                };
        }
        function highlightFeature(e) {
            var layer = e.target;

            layer.setStyle({
            weight: 5,
            color: '#666',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });

        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
            layer.bringToFront();
            }
        info.update(e);
        }

        function resetHighlight(e) {
            geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
        }

        function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
            layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: regionClicked
            });

            info.update();
        }

        function regionClicked(e)
        {
            var zipcode = e.target.feature.id;
            var url = "/data/zipcode/"+zipcode;
            return alert(scope.getData(url));
        }   

    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: "<div id=\"map\"></div>",
        link: linker
    };
});
```

regionClicked(e) is the function where the function acts up a mouse click and makes an ajax call to return the Plotly url.

I follow the principles of AngularJS, but with LeafletJS I'm finding it very hard to make this app Angular-like.

**EDIT:** I have refactored the code to make it more presentable. I now have a controller that returns the url. To make it clear, I would like to replace the template  with an iframe plotly embed housing the url received from the ajax call.

Comment: Hi, why not using the [Angular Leaflet Directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Plotly url"? Can you describe what do you want to achieve or what do you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can implement the communication between the controller and the directive: [Plunker](http://goo.gl/ey4wPc). It is pretty simple but demonstrates the idea. Once you understand it you can do some variations.

How usually the communication goes:

- implement functions in the controller
- pass them to the directive
- call them from within the directive when needed (don't forget to call $scope.$apply() if needed)